# I have a question about std::shared_ptr deleter

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I want the shared_ptr owns pointer array.
So I created the shared_ptr like next.

```cpp
// shared_ptr
std::shared_ptr<Foo* []> sptr(new Foo*[N], array_deleter<Foo*>());
...
sptr[i] = new Foo(...);
```

And this is the deleter for the sptr.

```cpp
// deleter
template <typename T>
struct array_deleter
{
    void operator()(T const* p)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            delete p[i];
        }

        delete[] p;
    }
};
```

The deleter does works well. But I need more deleter for other class.
What I want is just a size of array. In above code, it is the N.

I want to receive the N as a deleter parameter. Is it possible? or is there any way?

Comment: Dynamic c-style arrays don't keep track of their own size. This is one of the many reasons you should prefer using `std::vector` or similar containers.

Comment: Might making `N` as template parameter? And specify it everytime.

Comment: @songyuanyao 
I tried to add N as template parameter, but didn't work. maybe a deleter signature fixed.

Comment: @super you mean like this? shared_ptr<vector<int*>> sptr;

Thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: @woohyeon Using `int*` inside the vector seems like a terrible idea. Not really sure why you need to use pointers everywhere. You have a shared pointer to a dynamic array of pointers.... ???

Comment: @super
Um.. oh you meant "vector<shared_ptr<int>>" ? 

I just needed the array for saving pointers and I wanted to make shared_ptr owns the array.

If I have just the shared_ptr, I can access like this simply. sptr[0], sptr[1]...

Comment: @woohyeon You should generally avoid pointers (especially raw ones) if there's not a good reason to use them. It really comes down to ownership. Who owns the objects in the array? If the array itself owns them (which the fact that you want a deleter that cleans them up indicates) you should probably not use pointer at all. Just use a `vector<int>` or `vector<vector<int>>`.

Comment: @super I don't understand why not. What is the problem in this code? 

` std::shared_ptr<Foo* []> sptr(new Foo*[5], array_deleter<Foo*>()); ` 

for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{  sptr[i] = new Foo(...); }`
 
I checked memory leak doesn't happen. works well.

If I use `vector<vector<Foo>>`, each element is a vector. like this. 
[vector<Foo>], [vector<Foo>], ....

(I thought that doesn't  it memory waste?)

But if I use pointer, shared_ptr -> [int*], [int*], [int*], ... 

Plz let me know what is the problem in this code, so that I won't mistake again.

Comment: @woohyeon There no memory leak in that code, no. But you are still manually managing your memory, which is error prone. If you instead use `vector<vector<Foo>>` you get the same thing, but don't have to manage memory manually. It doesn't waste memory. It's just more safe and easier to use.

Comment: @woohyeon Additionally you get things like iterators, the size of the vectors, proper move sematics, a bunch of useful member functions ect ect.

Comment: @super Thank you for the answer. I understand what you meant!